# D3.js Geo - Animated pathline crossing earth edges issue

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, transition, geo

I've been working on drawing a simplify animated voyage of James Cook on a map with D3.
Projection is equirectangular. The data is a set of geographical points which I use to create pathLines bewteen two points looping the JSON object.
I animate then for each patLines a ship and draw the line step by step using stroke-dasharray.

NB: I didn't include TopoJSON data on the Jsfiddle.

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yoannlal/16yrfka5/22/

```
var cook = [
            {"name": "Plymouth", "year": 1768, "month": 08, "day": 26, "coordinates": [-4.1397, 50.3706]},
            {"name": "Rio de Janeiro", "year": 1768, "month": 12, "day": 06, "coordinates": [-43.2436, -22.9083]},
            {"name": "Car horn", "year": 1769, "month": 01, "day": 20,  "coordinates": [-67.2717, -55.9797]},
            {"name": "Pacific", "year": 1769, "month": 03, "day": 01,  "coordinates": [-110.55, -38.733333]},
            {"name": "Possession Island", "year": 1770, "month": 09, "day": 22, "coordinates": [142.3959417, -10.7226237]},
            {"name": "Cape of Good Hope", "year": 1771, "month": 04, "day": 15, "coordinates": [18.4737341, -34.3570248]},
            {"name": "Saint Helena", "year": 1771, "month": 05, "day": 15, "coordinates": [-5.7, -15.9333]},
            {"name": "Baleares", "year": 1771, "month": 06, "day": 15, "coordinates": [-25.6, 37.7]},
            {"name": "Plymouth", "year": 1771, "month": 07, "day": 13, "coordinates": [-4.1397, 50.3706]}
        ];

var width = document.getElementById('map').offsetWidth;
var height = document.getElementById('map').offsetHeight;

var projection = d3.geo.equirectangular()
.scale((width/640)*100)
.translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
.projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("#map").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);


function transition(ship, route, routeNbr, delay) {

    var l = route.node().getTotalLength(); 

    var dateStart = new Date(cook[routeNbr].year, cook[routeNbr].month, cook[routeNbr].day);
    var dateEnd = new Date(cook[routeNbr+1].year, cook[routeNbr+1].month, cook[routeNbr+1].day);

    var journeyDays = d3.time.days(dateStart, dateEnd);
    voyageDays[routeNbr] = journeyDays.length;


    if(routeNbr === 0){
        voyageTransition[0] = ship.transition()                                                      .duration(voyageDays[routeNbr]*coef)
           .ease("linear")
           .attrTween("transform", tweenCustom(ship, route, journeyDays));
                }

    else{
        voyageTransition[routeNbr] = voyageTransition[routeNbr-1].transition()                  .duration(voyageDays[routeNbr]*coef)
        .delay(delay)
        .ease("linear")
       .attrTween("transform", tweenCustom(ship, route, journeyDays));

    }

    delay += (voyageDays[routeNbr]*coef);
    routeNbr++; 

    if(routeNbr < cook.length-1){
        discover(ship, routeNbr, cook[routeNbr], cook[routeNbr+1], delay);
    }


    function tweenCustom(ship, route, journeyDays){

        var header = d3.select(".header");
        var n = 0;
        return function(i) {
            return function(t) {

                var l = route.node().getTotalLength();
                var p = route.node().getPointAtLength(t * l);

                interpolate = d3.interpolateString("0," + l, l + "," + l);

                route.style("stroke-dasharray", interpolate(t));


                return "translate(" + (p.x - 10) + "," + (p.y - 10) + "), scale(0.1)";
            }
        }
    }

}

function discover(ship, routeNbr, startPoint, endPoint, delay){

    var route = svg.append("path")
    .attr("class","route")
    .datum({type: "LineString", coordinates: [startPoint.coordinates, endPoint.coordinates]}) 
    .attr("d", path)
    .attr("fill","none")
    .attr("stroke", "#5f4c4c")
    .style('stroke-dasharray', function(d) {
                                var l = d3.select(this).node().getTotalLength();
                                return "0, "+l;
                            });

    transition(ship, route, routeNbr, delay);
}

var ship = svg.append("path")
.attr("d", "M 93,0 L 0,81 L 0,82 L 37,104 L 32,108 L 54,128 L 182,128 L 182,118 L 183,115 L 189,112 L 192,105 L 191,92 L 191,87 L 193,81 L 153,30 L 156,20 L 156,19 L 146,21 L 133,4 L 131,3 L 95,0 L 93,0 z M 93,1 L 93,21 L 71,26 L 71,27 C 67,37 67,49 73,59 L 73,61 C 69,70 71,80 76,88 L 74,88 L 70,92 C 52,64 53,37 69,22 C 84,8 93,1 93,1 z M 95,1 L 131,4 L 131,24 L 112,29 L 112,30 L 113,30 L 110,44 C 105,37 109,26 113,19 L 113,18 L 95.5,20.5 L 95,1 z M 133,5 L 145,21 L 133.5,23.5 L 133,5 z M 109,20 L 95.5,25 L 95.5,22.5 L 109,20 z M 154,20.5 L 148,23 L 147,22 L 154,20.5 z M 146,22.5 L 147,23.5 L 133.5,28 L 133.5,25.5 L 146,22.5 z M 93,23 L 93,25 C 88,27 82,28 77,26 L 93,23 z M 131,26 L 131,28 L 118,29 L 131,26 z M 153,31 L 192,81 L 168,85 L 161,90 C 157,80 159,68 162,58 L 163,58 L 163,56 L 162,56 C 155,49 151,41 153,31 z M 109,53 L 97,55 L 97,54 L 109,53 z M 94,54 L 94,55.5 L 76,59 C 81.130294,54.824798 88.927822,54.383689 94,54 z M 111,54.5 L 97,59 L 97,57 L 111,54.5 z M 94,57.5 L 94,60 C 89,61 83,61 78,60 L 94,57.5 z M 158,57 L 136,60 L 136,58 C 143,56.5 150.5,57 158,57 z M 160,58 C 152.5,62 144.5,64.5 136,65 L 136,62 L 160,58 z M 132,59 L 132,60.5 L 122,63 L 132,59 z M 114,62 L 116,65 L 113,73 C 113,73 112,66 114,62 z M 132,62.5 L 132,65 L 119,65 L 132,62.5 z M 69,92 C 61,102 51.5,105 40,100 L 2,81 C 2,81 5,77 9,75 C 31,62.5 52,81 69,92 z M 95,86 L 95,88 L 82,89 C 86,87.5 90.5,86.5 95,86 z M 98,86 L 112,87 L 98,88 L 98,86 z M 112,88 C 112.5,92.5 115.31835,98.819349 116,100 L 116,102 L 134,101 L 134,113 C 120,115 114,108 109,96 L 103,95 L 102,91 L 98,91 L 98,89 L 112,88 z M 95,89 L 95,90 L 88.5,89.5 L 95,89 z M 134,96 L 134,99 L 121,100 L 134,96 z M 137,96 L 154,97 L 137,99 L 137,96 z M 154,99 C 154,110 147,113.5 137,113 L 137,101 L 154,99 z ")
.attr("class", "ship");


var routeNbr = 0;

            // Coef pour multplication des durées d'animation
var coef = 20;
var voyageTransition = [];
var voyageDays = [];
var delay = 0;

discover(ship, routeNbr, cook[routeNbr], cook[routeNbr+1], delay);
```

**One issue**:

When the path has to cross the earth edge (on the pacific, from Tahiti to NZ for example), the tween function seems to loose smoothness. The timer (t) inside the tween is slower and takes less values. Plus, stroke-dasharray starts on two points and draw an unwanted line on the middle of the pathline.

One solution was to analyse the pathline and split it on each L on the pathSegList[i], create two suPath and send it to the animation, but my code lines are doubled with that one. 
Any better solution to propose or explanation why the timer and stroke-dasharray are working that way on this example ?

**One question**:

One the same example, I'm trying to link the animation timer and the date. I'm calculating the days difference between two points and use it to control the current pathline animation duration. Any idea how can I link this number to the timer (t) inside the tween function that I can have the dates display on the map and the correct location ?

Thanks a lot !

Yoann

Comment: I like the idea because in my project I also used the path of persons, but without animations. But anyway I basically like the idea pretty much. Did you already see http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1705868 http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5649592 and http://zevross.com/blog/2014/09/30/use-the-amazing-d3-library-to-animate-a-path-on-a-leaflet-map/ which is giving much info about the code. Good luck with this and I would like to tsee the final result :)

Comment: [This blog post](http://www.tnoda.com/blog/2014-04-02) should also help.

Comment: Thx ! I believe the crossing earth edge issue is more common that I thought, as you can see in the flight animation example, the flight svg is acting weird while crossing the pacific...! Keep you posted if I find something